# How to bulk index HTML files with Solr Cell?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a directory that contains 200 million HTML files (don't look at me, I didn't create this mess, I just have to deal with it). I need to index every HTML file in that directory into Solr. I've been reading guides on getting the job done, and I've got something going right now. After about an hour, I've got about 100k indexed, meaning this is going to take roughly 85 days.

I'm indexing the files to a standalone Solr server, running on a c4.8xlarge AWS EC2 instance. Here's the output from `free -m` with the Solr server running, and the indexer I wrote running as well:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         60387      12981      47405          0         19       4732
-/+ buffers/cache:       8229      52157
Swap:            0          0          0
```

As you can see, I'm doing pretty good on resources. I increased the number of maxWarmingSearchers to 200 in my Solr config, because I was getting the error:

> Exceeded limit of maxWarmingSearchers=2, try again later

Alright, but I don't think increasing that limit was really the right approach. I think the issue is that for each file, I am doing a commit, and I should be doing this in bulk (say 50k files / commit), but I'm not entirely sure how to adapt this code for that, and every example I see does a single file at a time. I really need to do everything I can to make this run as fast as possible, since I don't really have 85 days to wait on getting the data in Solr.

Here's my code:

**Index.java**

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;


public class Index {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String directory = "/opt/html";
        String solrUrl = "URL";
        final int QUEUE_SIZE = 250000;
        final int MAX_THREADS = 300;

        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_SIZE);


        SolrProducer producer = new SolrProducer(queue, directory);
        new Thread(producer).start();

        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_THREADS; i++)
            new Thread(new SolrConsumer(queue, solrUrl)).start();
    }
}
```

**Producer.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class SolrProducer implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private String directory;

    public SolrProducer(BlockingQueue<String> queue, String directory) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(directory);
            Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    if (!attrs.isDirectory()) {
                        try {
                            queue.put(file.toString());
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
import co.talentiq.common.net.SolrManager;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class SolrConsumer implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private static SolrManager sm;

    public SolrConsumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue, String url) {
        this.queue = queue;
        if (sm == null)
            this.sm = new SolrManager(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String file = queue.take();
                sm.indexFile(file);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**SolrManager.java**

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.ContentStreamUpdateRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class SolrManager {
    private static String urlString;
    private static SolrClient solr;

    public SolrManager(String url) {
        urlString = url;
        if (solr == null)
            solr = new HttpSolrClient(url);
    }

    public void indexFile(String fileName) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
        String solrId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        up.addFile(new File(fileName), solrId);
        up.setParam("literal.id", solrId);
        up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
        solr.request(up);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `up.setCommitWithin(10000);` to make Solr just commit automagically at least every ten seconds. Increase the value to make Solr commit each minute (60000) or each ten minutes (600000). Remove the explicit commit (`setAction(..)`).

Another option is to [configure `autoCommit` in your configuration file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig#UpdateHandlersinSolrConfig-autoCommit).

You might also be able to index quicker by moving the HTML extraction process out from Solr (and just submitting the text to be indexed), or expanding the amount of servers you're posting to (more nodes in the cluster).

Answer (score 0):

Am guessing you wont be searching the index in parallel while documents are being indexed. So here are the things that you could do.

- You can configure the auto commit option in your solrconfig.xml. It can be done based on number of documents / time interval. For you, number of documents option would make more sense.
- Remove that call to setAction() method in ContentStreamUpdateRequest object. you can maintain a count for number of calls made to indexFile() method. Say if it reaches 25000/10000 (based on your heap you can limit the count) then for that indexing call alone you can perform the commit using the SolrClient object like solr.commit(). so that the commit will be made once for specified count.

Let me know the results. Good Luck!